# Debian live-build can't locate linux-image-686-pae

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, live-usb, livecd

I'm trying to use `live-build` to construct a minimal Debian image containing the wireless firmware for my laptop.  I get this error:

```
[2019-02-04 18:56:40] lb chroot_install-packages install
P: Begin installing packages (install pass)...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-686-pae
```

---

My build process goes something like this:

Create a brand new VM using Vagrant box [`generic/debian9`](https://app.vagrantup.com/generic/boxes/debian9).  Once created, SSH in and run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install live-build
```

Following the [live-build manual](https://live-team.pages.debian.net/live-manual/html/live-manual/the-basics.en.html#179), [prep the build directory](https://live-team.pages.debian.net/live-manual/html/live-manual/examples.en.html#819):

```
mkdir -p my_build/auto && cd my_build
cp /usr/share/doc/live-build/examples/auto/* auto/
```

Edit `auto/config` to read as follows.  I am building an image specifically for a Dell XPS15 9560 and want an `amd64` architecture/linux kernel<sup>1</sup>.

```
   #!/bin/sh

   set -e

   lb config noauto \
       --architectures amd64 \
       --linux-flavours 686-pae \
       --binary-images iso-hybrid \
       --archive-areas "main contrib non-free" \
       --bootappend-live "boot=live persistence components hostname=bakerst username=holmes sudo" \
       "${@}"
```

Generate a config tree using the `auto/config` just created:

```
lb config
```

Create `config/package-lists/my.list.chroot`:

```
firmware-atheros
sudo
```

Now, build:

```
sudo lb build
```

This generates the error.

The problem seems related to the [`linux-image-686-pae`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/linux-image-686-pae) package.  My understanding is that `live-build` works by chrooting into the build and running `apt-get`.  Doing the same in the non-chroot environment returns an error:

```
vagrant@debian9:~/my_build$ sudo apt-get install linux-image-686-pae
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-686-pae
```

One possible error could be using the wrong sources.  Yet, I'm pulling from the main Debian repo.  Checking `/etc/apt/sources.list`, I have `main contrib non-free` appended to each entry.  I'm not sure what else to check.

---

<sup>1</sup>I mention this because most tutorials use `i386`.  I believe `686-pae` is valid.

Comment: 686-pae is a 32 bits kernel, not an amd64 (aka x86_64) kernel. While one could imagine the opposite (amd64 kernel with i386 debian arch for userland), your combination doesn't make sense to me

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @A.B, 686-pae is for a 32 bit kernel.  Removing that option resolves the issue:

```
   #!/bin/sh

   set -e

   lb config noauto \
       --architectures amd64 \
       --binary-images iso-hybrid \
       --archive-areas "main contrib non-free" \
       --bootappend-live "boot=live persistence components hostname=bakerst username=holmes sudo" \
       "${@}"
```